# Why log-space reduction is used for NL-completeness while PSPACE reduction isn't used for PSPACE completeness?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, reductions, complexity-classes, space-complexity

NL-Complete languages are defined by Log-space reduction, while PSPACE complete languages are defined by poly-time many-to-one reduction.

According to these posts :

[Why not polynomial-space reductions for $PSPACE$-hardness?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/96947/why-not-polynomial-space-reductions-for-pspace-hardness?rq=1)

[PSpace-completeness under PSpace reductions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87293/pspace-completeness-under-pspace-reductions)

Every PSPACE language would be PSPACE-Complete if we defined completeness using a
Poly-**SPACE** reduction (instead of a poly-**TIME** reduction).

My question is, why does Log-space reduction doesn't imply completeness for every $L \in NL$, for the same reasoning?

Take any **A,B $\in$ NL** , and fixed $y,n$ s.t $y\in A$ and $n\notin A$.

We can define the following log-space reduction **$f$** :
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\ y&\text{if }x\in A\\
                    \ n&\text{if }x\notin A.\end{cases}$$

Just solve A in log-space and let our output be the fixed instance according to the right case.

How come log-space reductions are NOT useless for NL completeness while Pspace reductions are useless for PSPACE completeness? What am I missing ?

Comment: Your reduction runs in nondeterministic logspace, but not necessarily in deterministic logspace.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus So ; $f(x)$ needs to be computed using a determenistic TM , 
and thus my reduction runs in nondeterministic logspace- since solving provlem A might require using a nondeterministic machine (since $A \in NL$)
While since $PSPACE = NPSPACE$ every problem in NPSPACE is also solveable in poly-space using a determenistic TM , thus the function $f(x)$ runs in determenistic time , and the reduction works as required ?

Comment: It is conjectured that L and NL are different. Savitch’s theorem, used to show that PSPACE=NPSPACE, only implies that NL can be simulated in space $O(\log^2n)$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Got it ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reduction $f$ works in *nondeterministic* logspace, which is conjectured to be stronger than logspace. Assuming this conjecture, it follows that the concept of NL-completeness is not trivial, that is, not all problems in NL are NL-complete; in particular, problems in L are not NL-complete.

What might be confusing you is that PSPACE=NPSPACE, which is proved using [Savitch's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitch%27s_theorem). In the context of logarithmic space, the theorem only shows that problems in NL can be decided in space $O(\log^2 n)$.